# how to remove action listener?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm beginner at Java and I can't figure out what's wrong in my code. I've tried almost everything and it didn't work. To be specyfic, I'm designing a game which is about collecting rubbish to the bins
If the image of rubbish displays , I want to show on my JLabel if it's ok or not

```
        final JLabel smiec=new JLabel();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 0;       
        c.weighty = 1.0;   
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; 
        c.gridx = 2;       
        c.gridwidth = 2;   
        c.gridheight = 3;   
        smiec.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(""));

        final Random generator = new Random();
        smiec.setText("Kliknij aby rozpocząć!");
        smiec.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        background.add(smiec,c);

        final String text="ok";
        final String text2="zle";

        smiec.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){ 
              public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){ 
                ActionListener tak, tak2, tak3, tak4, tak5;
                 int a=0;
                 smiec.setText(null);
                 domowyBudzet.setText(null);
                 a=16- generator.nextInt(17);
                 ImageIcon smiecImg = new ImageIcon("odpad"+a+".png");
                 smiec.setIcon(smiecImg);
                 background.repaint();
                 boolean flagA, flagB, flagC, flagD, flagE, flagF;
                 if(a==0||a==6||a==11){
                     flagA=true;
                 }
                 else{
                     flagA=false;
                 }
                 if(a==1){
                     flagB=true;
                 }
                 else{
                     flagB=false;
                 }
                 if(a==2){
                     flagC=true;
                 }
                 else{
                     flagC=false;
                 }
                 if(a==3||a==4||a==14||a==16){
                     flagD=true;
                 }
                 else{
                     flagD=false;
                 }
                 if(a==5||a==9||a==10||a==13){
                     flagE=true;
                 }
                 else{
                     flagE=false;
                 }
                 if(a==7||a==8||a==12||a==15){
                     flagF=true;
                 }
                 else{
                     flagF=false;
                 }
                 if(flagA==true){
                    tak = new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                                if(evt.getSource()==buttonPapier){
                                domowyBudzet.setText(text);
                                domowyBudzet.repaint();
                                }
                                else{
                                    domowyBudzet.setText(text2);
                                    domowyBudzet.repaint();
                                }

                            }
                     };
                     buttonPapier.removeActionListener(tak);
                     flagA=false;
                 }
                if(flagB==true){
                    ActionListener tak1 = new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            if(evt.getSource()==buttonBiale){
                            domowyBudzet.setText(text);
                            domowyBudzet.repaint();
                            }
                            else{
                                domowyBudzet.setText(text2);
                                domowyBudzet.repaint();
                            }
                        }
                 };
                 buttonBiale.removeActionListener(tak1);
                    flagB=false;

                }
                if(flagC==true){
                    tak2 = new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            if(evt.getSource()==buttonKolor){
                            domowyBudzet.setText(text);
                            domowyBudzet.repaint();
                            }
                            else{
                                domowyBudzet.setText(text2);
                                domowyBudzet.repaint();
                            }
                        }
                 };
                    flagC=false; 


                }
                if(flagD==true){
                    tak3 = new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            if(evt.getSource()==buttonReszta){
                            domowyBudzet.setText(text);
                            domowyBudzet.repaint();
                            }
                            else{
                                domowyBudzet.setText(text2);
                                domowyBudzet.repaint();
                            }
                        }
                 };
                 buttonReszta.removeActionListener(tak3);
                    flagD=false;
                }
                if(flagE==true){
                    tak4 = new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            if(evt.getSource()==buttonPlastik){
                            domowyBudzet.setText(text);
                            domowyBudzet.repaint();
                            }
                            else{
                                domowyBudzet.setText(text2);
                                domowyBudzet.repaint();
                            }
                        }
                 };
                    flagE=false;
                    buttonPlastik.removeActionListener(tak4);

                }
                if(flagF==true){
                    tak5 = new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            if(evt.getSource()==buttonKompost){
                            domowyBudzet.setText(text);
                            domowyBudzet.repaint();
                            }
                            else{
                                domowyBudzet.setText(text2);
                                domowyBudzet.repaint();
                            }
                        }
                 };
                 buttonKompost.removeActionListener(tak5);
                    flagF=false;

                }


              }
        });
```

Comment: Also your assumption that it is OK to dump 500 lines of code of no relevance to your problem is an insult to the volunteers on this site.

Comment: When I am new to a language, I always start with a [small example program](http://sscce.org/) that focuses on a particular part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're not holding a reference to your listener. In order to remove a listener you should hold a reference to it, and then you can pass the reference to the remove listener method.

For example you're doing:

```
smiec.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){ ... });
```

But if you did something like this you'd be able to remove the mouse listener later.

```
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {...};
smiec.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
...
smiec.removeMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

You can see the Java Doc for `JLabel`, specifically for the `removeMouseListener` method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#removeMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29).